# Using bigquery client inside asyncio causes hanging issue in "OpenSSL/SSL.py", in recv_into

Tags: python, google-bigquery, openssl, python-asyncio

We are doing some read operations using python bigquery library.

```
Python version: Python 3.8.10
Google bigquery package: https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/ (version: 2.30.1)
```

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import bigquery

import logging
import asyncio
import faulthandler
import traceback
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor

logger = logging.getLogger('test')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

def get_big_query_client(source_details):
   print("get client")
   credentials_dict = source_details['auth_config']
   credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)
   project_id = credentials_dict["project_id"]
   client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)
   return client

async def check_and_run_dd_for_tenants(tenant_ids, source_detail, table_name):
   await asyncio.gather(*[flatten_column_details_of_dataset(source_detail, table_name) for tenant_id in tenant_ids])

async def flatten_column_details_of_dataset(source_details, table_name):

   curr_column_data = []
  
   client = get_big_query_client(source_details)
   schema_name = 'test_schema'
   query_table_name = f"{schema_name}.{table_name}"
   details = {'query_table_name':query_table_name}
   table_reference = details.get("query_table_name")

   try:
       table_details = client.get_table(table_reference)
       print("table_details",table_details)

       for _schema_data in table_details.schema:
           data_type = _schema_data.field_type

   except Exception as exp:
       logger.error(exp)
       logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
       pass
   finally:
       client.close()
   return curr_column_data

def main():
   logger = logging.getLogger("Run DD")
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   faulthandler.enable(all_threads=True)
   faulthandler.dump_traceback_later(180, repeat=True)

   source_details = {
       "auth_config": {
           "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "*************",
           "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
           "client_email": "**************",
           "client_id": "****************",
           "client_x509_cert_url": "**********************",
           "private_key": "*****************",
           "private_key_id": "***************",
           "project_id": "**********************",
           "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
           "type": "service_account"
       }
   }
   table_names = ['test1']
   tenant_id = []
   for i in range(1,30):
       tenant_id.append(i)
   for table in table_names:
       res = asyncio.run(check_and_run_dd_for_tenants(tenant_id, source_details, table))
       print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

We are trying to run things concurrently using asyncio. When we run this code, the code is hanging sometimes.

Upon examining the trace using `faulthandler` , we got the following trace.

```
Thread 0x00007fde83fff700 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1799 in recv_into
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 319 in recv_into
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669 in readinto
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 277 in _read_status
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 316 in begin
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1348 in getresponse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440 in _make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699 in urlopen
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 489 in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 701 in send
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587 in request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/auth/transport/requests.py", line 480 in request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 379 in _do_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 341 in _make_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http/__init__.py", line 482 in api_request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 190 in retry_target
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 283 in retry_wrapped_func
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 760 in _call_api
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 1012 in get_table
  File "/connector_interfaces/big_query.py", line 804 in get_files
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 80 in _worker
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870 in run
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 890 in _bootstrap
```

We can see this line in the trace.
`table_details = client.get_table(table_reference)`

Normally we will have async and await for the function in our code. But since we are using library, we cannot add async/await to the library's normal functions.

**Attempted fixes:**

1. We have tried with introducing lock

```py
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()
lock.acquire()

# Having our code related to reading here
table_details = client.get_table(table_reference)

lock.release()
```

This approach didn't work.

2. Adding timeout to `get_table` function.
   `table_details = client.get_table(table_reference, timeout=180)`
   Still we got the same error.
3. Setting socket blocking mode to False

```py
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setblocking(False)
s.settimeout(300)
```

4. Having the read part in a separate function and calling it using

```py
loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
res = await loop.run_in_executor(None, my_new_read_func,arg1)
print(res)
```

All 4 approaches we are facing issue.

How to avoid this hanging issue?

NOTE:

Corresponding issue is raised in bigquery's github repo also.
https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/issues/1674

The tables that we have are also smaller tables only.

Comment: Hi Nandha, As mentioned in the [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75582557/18329678) and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), Asyncio doesn't run things in parallel; it runs them concurrently. Could you check those links ? This might help you resolve the issue.

Comment: @DhirajSingh Updated the description. Changed Parallely to Concurrently.

Comment: This doesn't directly address the problem with SSL, but you're not quite using `asyncio` correctly.  When you're running your for loop and executing `asyncio.run(...)`, each of those "runs" occurs sequentially, not concurrently, as you might think.  Take a look at using [TaskGroup](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) or using a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) to use a [producer/consumer](https://www.dataleadsfuture.com/unleashing-the-power-of-python-asyncios-queue/)-like pattern.  I'm assuming the code works without concurrency?